# how to i target a another div with jquery or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have three different divs red, blue, green and yellow. red contains an input box. am trying to hide yellow if the input box in red is clicked(focus)

HTML

```
<div class="red">
    <form>
        <input class="s" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="blue"> blue </div>
<div class="green"> green </div>
<div class="yellow"> yellow </div>
```

CSS

```
.red, .blue, .green, .yellow
{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.red{
    background: red;
}

.blue{
    background: blue;
}

.green{
    background: green;
}

.yellow{
    background: yellow;
}

.s:focus{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.s:focus + yellow{
    display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8acwjf3o/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(function(){

   $(".s").on("focus",function()
   {
        $(".yellow").hide();
   });
   $(".s").on("blur",function()
   {
        $(".yellow").show();
   });

});
```

```css
.red, .blue, .green, .yellow
{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
.red{
    background: red;
}
.blue{
    background: blue;
}
.green{
    background: green;
}
.yellow{
    background: yellow;
}
.s:focus{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.s:focus + yellow{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red">
<form>
<input class="s" placeholder="Search">
</form>
</div>
<div class="blue"> top </div>
<div class="green"> middle </div>
<div class="yellow"> bottom </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is fairly easy to do it with jquery;

```
(function() {
    $('.red input').on({
        click: function() { // maybe you'd prefer on focus?
            $('.yellow').fadeOut();
        }
    })
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

The + selector in CSS only works with adjacent elements.  In this case, you'd want to use javascript.  JQuery makes it particularly easy:

```
$('.s').focus(function() {
   $('.yellow').hide(); 
}). blur(function() {
    $('.yellow').show();
});
```

Here's the revised JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w10cw8tc/

```js
$(function(){
    $('.s').focus(function() {
        $('.yellow').hide(); 
    }). blur(function() {
        $('.yellow').show();
    });
});
```

```css
.red, .blue, .green, .yellow {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
.red{
    background: red;
}
.blue{
    background: blue;
}
.green{
    background: green;
}
.yellow{
    background: yellow;
}
.s:focus{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red">
<form>
    <input class="s" placeholder="Search" />
</form>
</div>
<div class="blue"> top </div>
<div class="green"> middle </div>
<div class="yellow"> bottom </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers will work. Here's a fiddle form if you prefer that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".red input").focus(function() {
        $(".yellow").hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8acwjf3o/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use jQuery `.focus()` function for this

```
$( "#search" ).focus(function() {
    $( ".yellow" ).hide();
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8acwjf3o/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```js
$('#search').on('focus', function () {
    $('#yellow').hide('fast');
});
```

```css
    .colored {
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #f00;
    }
    #red {
        background: red;
    }
    #blue {
        background: blue;
    }
    #green {
        background: green;
    }
    #yellow {
        background: yellow;
    }
    .s:focus {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .s:focus + yellow {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colored" id="red">
    <form>
        <input id="search" placeholder="Search" />
    </form>
</div>
<div class="colored" id="blue">blue</div>
<div class="colored" id="green">green</div>
<div class="colored" id="yellow">yellow</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS

```
.s:focus + yellow{
    display: none;
}
```

There are a couple of things which are wrong with this style, first would be a typo where you are missing '.' before 'yellow' class name for selection. Second; as there is no '.yellow' element adjacent to 'input.s' element, this style will never be applied. Reverse child to parent selector are not defined in CSS (yet!).

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll(".s")[0];
input.addEventListener("focus", function () {
    var yellow = document.querySelectorAll(".yellow")[0];
    yellow.style.display = "none";
});
```

or jQuery way :

```
$(".s").focus(function () {
    $(".yellow").hide();//You can use .hide() or .fadeOut() or .slideUp() or .slideDown() methods.
});
```